# Cannot FTP to a specific server and seemingly random intervals

Tags: ftp

I administer a server that's hosted at GoDaddy and at seemingly random times I'm unable to FTP to the server from my desktop machine. I am able to FTP to the server from another machine on the same LAN as my desktop machine and I'm able to FTP from my desktop machine to other servers without any issue.

Things I've tried so far:

- Set up logging at the Hardware Firewall on the Server and don't see any activity
- Trying multiple different FTP clients
- Checking to make sure the output from the tracert is the same for both the working and non-working desktop.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[Solved]
Turned out to be a faulty ethernet driver that I've been using since June 2009; there was an update the same year with no details associated with the update, but the procedure I used for recreating the issue doesn't work after a driver update. For the record, I found out that the FTP connection would start failing after a large download via FTP.

Comment: What OS are you running on these machines, both your own desktop machine that doesn't work and the other machines that do?

Comment: Server 2003 on the system that's not working.
Windows 7 on the system that is working. As a note, IPV6 is disabled on the Windows 7 machine.